google sheets IMPORTXML for currency prices
I want to retrieve a cell from website https://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/201511/30112015.xml in a google sheet by using IMPORTXML.
'Döviz Satış Forex Selling' column of  'USD/TRY' row, the value is 2.9161.
I tried 2 methods but it did not worked.
=IMPORTXML("https://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/201511/30112015.xml","/Currency CrossOrder[0]/ForexSelling")
=IMPORTXML("https://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/201511/30112015.xml","/html/body/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]")
for the second one I used inspect and copy full xpath by selecting 2.9161
expecting the value 2.9161

In your situation, how about the following XPath?
//*[local-name()='Currency'][@CrossOrder='0']/ForexSelling

When this is reflected in IMPORTXML, it becomes as follows.
=IMPORTXML("https://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/201511/30112015.xml","//*[local-name()='Currency'][@CrossOrder='0']/ForexSelling")

When this is used, the following result is obtained.


It worked. thank you

Retreiving a cell value using IMPORTXML
Kindly try to use this Google sheet formula:
=IMPORTXML("https://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/201511/30112015.xml", "//Currency[@Kod='USD']/ForexSelling")

This is the result:

REFERENCES:
IMPORTXML

=IMPORTXML("https://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/201511/30112015.xml", "//Currency[CurrencyCode='USD']/ForexSelling")

it did not workedç

You need to add an "@" to tell the function that, CurrencyCode is an attribute. So, this will work; =IMPORTXML("https://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/201511/30112015.xml", "//Currency[@CurrencyCode='USD']/ForexSelling")
